# Give a VM internet access, but not access to other systems within the network?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, pfsense

Scenario: I have Ubuntu desktop with a Windows 8.1 vm via virtualbox.

It has internet access and is currently set to NAT with it's own IP range. Putting it into bridged mode gives it an IP address from the router and places it on the same subnet as everything else.

What I'd like to achieve:

Have the VM allowed internet access, but not allow the VM to access other internal systems within the network (other servers)

I have a pfSense router. I realise I need to tunnel the VM thru to the router directly, but not sure how to make this happen.

It doesn't matter if other devices on the network can or can't see the VM

Answer (score 1):

The NAT network in VirtualBox would still allow it to reach machines in your LAN ...

Where is the pfSense router? Is it between your host machine and the rest of your subnet/lan?

You could use host-only networking in virtual box, set up your host machine as a router with a simple iptables script, use that script to forward connections from inside (vboxnet0 probably) to only your default gateway, and deny all access to any other machine in whatever subnet your local network (that you want to prevent access to) is using.

Comment: Unfortunately pfSense is on the other side of a switch. My whole network is connected to that switch. I think I understand your second part, are you able to point me towards an example I could follow elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You have two solution :
1-setup specific network in your virtualization . Same as setup vswitch with specific access
2- block remote up ( internal ip range) at firewall  for example

rule to the host: block (local IP = all, program=virtualbox.exe, remote IP = {range you want to block})

Answer (score 0):

It returns to your router configuration option called **client isolation** or **Wireless Isolation** you have to turn it off